# Quasar2 How to load rules from external json file and use them?

Tags: json, validation, vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar 2 and building components from external JSON file. It works except for `:rules`. How to effectively read the `rules = "[val => val.toString()... || 'Warning....!']"` and assign it to the Quasar Vue template? I have tried things like `:rules="data.rules"`, ``` :rules="``${data.rules}``" ``` but haven't had any luck with it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:rules="getRules"

  props: {
    rule: String,
    rules: Array
  },

  computed: {
    getRules() {
      return [eval(this.rule)];
    },
```